# Creating Rowtests with SpecFlow

Tags: specflow, rowtest

I am trying to create row tests using SpecFlow and the Microsoft built-in Test Framework, something along these lines:

```
Scenario Outline: Test Calculator
  Given I have entered <x> into the calculator
  And I have entered <y> into the calculator
  When I press add
  Then the result should be <result> on the screen

Examples:
  | x | y | result|
  | 1 | 2 | 3|
  | 2 | 2 | 4|
```

The problem I am facing is that given any step in the Scenario Outline a separate step method is auto-generated for each value from the Examples table. I would like to be able to implement for each step a generic method receiving input values as parameters but it just does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it looks like it works as expected, what I was missing were quotes around input parameters placeholders:

```
Scenario Outline: Test Calculator
  Given I have entered "<x>" into the calculator
  And I have entered "<y>" into the calculator
  When I press add
  Then the result should be "<result>" on the screen

Examples:
  | x | y | result|
  | 1 | 2 | 3|
  | 2 | 2 | 4|
```

Comment: hmm strange. The [official documentation](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Unit-test-providers) says that VS2010 does NOT support rowtests.

Comment: I have the same problem with VS 2012 update 2. The strange thing is that I write some features without quote in update 1, and it works like a charm. Probably something change since that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in VS 2012.  I think it may be a bug with SpecFlow, because when I change the Scenario Outline to only be a Scenario, it generates everything correctly.  All the documentation says you should not have to surround the placeholders in quotes.

In short, my solution is to change it to a Scenario to generate the steps.  But don't forget, you have to change it back to a Scenario Outline to compile.  This is what is working for me.